# Web Sockets DOM Object Detection

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to detect support for web sockets *without* `try`/`catch` and without errors in the consoles of any browsers including older browsers that do not support web sockets.

I have not found anything I feel is related to web socket under the `window` and `window.document` objects. Also I've tried `for (i in new)` which the browsers don't see to like.

Absolutely no frameworks or libraries.

Essentially the DOM object detection should be able to fit in to an `if` condition...

```
if (x in y) {alert('Web Sockets is supported.');}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if ("WebSocket" in window) // => it is supported
```

or this:

```
if( typeof(WebSocket) != "function" )  // => it is not supported
```

Comment: Worked and tested in Firefox 3.6 without any console errors; I'll accept when the time limit expires. Thank you.